# How can I get all child nodes of a tree

Tags: python

My tree has the following structure:

`tree={'0':('1','2','3'), '1':('4'), '2':('5','6'), '3':(), '4':('7','8'), '8':('9','10','11')}`

How can I write Python code to retrieve all given child nodes of a particular node? For example, if I give it node `4`, the code should retrieve `7, 8, 9, 10, 11`. For node `2`, it should retrieve `5, 6` and so on.

this is what I tried. but I am looking for something efficient.

```
import queue

tree={'0':('1','2','3'), '1':('4'), '2':('5','6'), '3':(), '4':('7','8'), '8':('9','10','11')}

num = input("what you want ")

q = queue.Queue()

q.put(num)

while not q.empty():
  n = q.get()
  for s in n:
    print(s)
    if s in tree:
      q.put(tree[s])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "something different"?  This works, right?  You have an iterative solution here.  You could do a recursive solution as well, without using a Queue, but it's not clear that's any better.

Comment: Not something different. i am looking for something efficient than this,

Comment: Also depends what you mean by efficient. In terms of big O I think this is the best you can do. Is there any reason you think there might be a more 'efficient' way of doing this?

Comment: Let's be honest.  Your tree traversal algorithm is never going to the performance bottleneck in your program.

Comment: You could implement a euler tour of the tree, in which case I think the lookup would be constant time, but honestly it's probably not worth the effort

Comment: @knosmos Haha . yup but Thanks